# How can I take a word from a text and make it into a link?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

```
<script>
function myClick(){
text = "<b><i>this is my text, THIS NEEDS TO BE A HYPERLINK </i></b>";
document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML  = document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML + text;
document.getElementById("heading1").style.textAlign="left";
document.getElementById("heading1").style.marginLeft="5px";

}
</script>
```

I only want the capital letters to be a hyperlink, it seems really easy but i cant find an answer online. (-.-)

Comment: will that text always be in all caps?

Comment: do you write text by yourself and you just need to automate it or you parse some html?

Comment: im not a big javascript guy, so i wanted to incorporate some html to make it a hyperlink. by the way that is not the actual text thats just an example. In the actual text i want only one word to be a hyperlink.

Comment: What will you link it to? I'm helping to provide an answer.

Comment: You need to use regex and `.replace()`

Comment: ok, that helped, but @LJ_1102 (/[A-Z\s]{2,}/) can this be used for none-capital letters. sorry for being a complete Javascript noob. :)

Comment: No @user3612995 it can't cause the `[A-Z]` matches any capital letters, this part is nothing to do with Javascript, and everything with **regular expressions**.

Comment: Are you planning to use a static link URL?

Comment: @user3612995 mh well I thought you were talking about capital letters, maybe you should refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it

```
var text = "<b><i>this is my text, THIS NEEDS TO BE A HYPERLINK </i></b>";
// Regex matching only uppercase letters and whitespaces where there
// have to be at least 2 in a row to match
var match = text.match(/[A-Z\s]{2,}/);
if (match && match.length) {
  match.forEach(function (str) {
    text = text.replace(str, '<a href="http://google.com/q=regex">' + str + '</a>');
  });
}
```

EDIT:
When you want to only replace a single word you can omit the \s group in the regex:
This regex still matches at minimum two uppercase characters to prevent misdetection of capitalized words or names.

```
    var match = text.match(/[A-Z]{2,}/);
```